# Import an angular 2 Module into my project

Tags: angular, odoo-8

i'm trying to import an angular2 module into my project.

This module will help me to get data using json rpc from our ERP system Odoo.

Here's the link of the module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-odoo-jsonrpc.

Here's what i did so far:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OdooRPCService } from 'angular2-odoo-jsonrpc';

**App.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`,
  providers: [OdooRPCService]

})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular';
constructor(odooRPC: OdooRPCService){
  odooRPC.init({
  odoo_server: "http://localhost:8069",
  http_auth: "duniakado@go2.web.id:password"
  });
  odooRPC.login('duniakado', 'duniakado@go2.web.id', 'password').then(res => {
  console.log('login success');
  }).catch( err => {
  console.error('login failed', err);
  })
} }
```

I did also  include the module in my index html

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2-odoo-jsonrpc/odoorpc.service.js"></script>
```

Then i include the module in my systemjs.config.js

**systemjs.config.js**

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'angular2-odoo-jsonrpc': 'npm:angular2-odoo-jsonrpc/odoorpc.service.js'


    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

I got a lot of errors in my console

```
core.umd.js:3491 EXCEPTION: No provider for Http!ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js:3491(anonymous function) @ core.umd.js:8362ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:229onInvoke @ core.umd.js:4405ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:228Zone.run @ zone.js:113(anonymous function) @ zone.js:509ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:262onInvokeTask @ core.umd.js:4396ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:261Zone.runTask @ zone.js:151drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:405ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:336
core.umd.js:3496 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js:3496(anonymous function) @ core.umd.js:8362ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:229onInvoke @ core.umd.js:4405ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:228Zone.run @ zone.js:113(anonymous function) @ zone.js:509ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:262onInvokeTask @ core.umd.js:4396ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:261Zone.runTask @ zone.js:151drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:405ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:336
core.umd.js:3497 Error: DI Error
    at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (core.umd.js:1225) [angular]
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (core.umd.js:1400) [angular]
    at new NoProviderError (core.umd.js:1439) [angular]
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (core.umd.js:3370) [angular]
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (core.umd.js:3407) [angular]
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (core.umd.js:3357) [angular]
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (core.umd.js:3119) [angular]
    at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (core.umd.js:8914) [angular]
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.injectorGet (core.umd.js:12314) [angular]
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.injectorGet (core.umd.js:12694) [angular]
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (host.ngfactory.js:19) [angular]
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.createHostView (core.umd.js:12270) [angular]
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.createHostView (core.umd.js:12678) [angular]
    at ComponentFactory.create (core.umd.js:7705) [angular]ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js:3497(anonymous function) @ core.umd.js:8362ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:229onInvoke @ core.umd.js:4405ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:228Zone.run @ zone.js:113(anonymous function) @ zone.js:509ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:262onInvokeTask @ core.umd.js:4396ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:261Zone.runTask @ zone.js:151drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:405ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:336
zone.js:392 Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for Http! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: NoProviderError {_nativeError: Error: No provider for Http!
    at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:300…, keys: Array[1], injectors: Array[1]} Error: DI Error
    at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1225:31) [angular]
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1400:20) [angular]
    at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1439:20) [angular]
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3370:23) [angular]
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3407:29) [angular]
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3357:29) [angular]
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3119:25) [angular]
    at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8914:56) [angular]
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.injectorGet (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12314:49) [angular]
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.injectorGet (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12694:53) [angular]
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:19:59) [angular]
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.createHostView (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12270:25) [angular]
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.createHostView (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12678:56) [angular]
    at ComponentFactory.create (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:7705:29) [angular]consoleError @ zone.js:392_loop_1 @ zone.js:421drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:425ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:336
zone.js:394 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Http!(…)
```

I should point the fact that my project Hello angular works fine then all becomes messed up with this module.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you should import HttpModule in your `@NgModule`

Comment: @yurzui thank you can you put your comment as an answer so i can close my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to import `HttpModule` in your `@NgModule`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ ... HttpModule, ...]
  ...
})
export class SomeModule {
```